# how can we enter value manually, which is not present as options, in a Select element for antd reactjs

Tags: antd

I want to search for an option in ANTD Select element. I am using 'showSearch' option to auto-suggestion for the Select element. But, the value I want to provide is not available as option for the element. Can we manually enter the value, which is not present as options, in that Select element and continue with the search.

We are able to enter values when 'mode=tags' is set, but we can select multiple options in that case. Is it possible to achieve the same, but restrict to only single option at a time, not multiple?

Answer (score 2):

To achieve, this you should try the antd `AutoComplete` component as it affords this kind of flexibility. It allows you to enter values that don't exist on the options list and you can only select a value at a time. You'll need to pass in `AutoComplete.Option` as children of the component (not the usual `Select.Option`)

Here's some documentation: https://ant.design/components/auto-complete/

Answer (score 2):

I also found it annoying that this feature is available in `tags` mode but not in `multiple`. I don't know if this is the best solution anyone could come up with, but I solved it for myself by wrapping the `Select` component with my own component like this:

```js
import { useState, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import { Select } from 'antd';


function FlexibleSelect(props) {

  const { options: baseOptions, ...selectProps } = props;

  const [options, setOptions] = useState([...baseOptions]);
  
  const currentValue = useRef();

  const onSearch = useCallback((value) => {

    currentValue.current = value;

    if (value && !baseOptions.some((op) => op.indexOf(value) === 0)) {
      setOptions([...baseOptions, value]);
    } else {
      setOptions([...baseOptions]);
    }
  }, [baseOptions]);

  return (
    <Select
      {...selectProps}
      showSearch
      onSearch={onSearch}
      options={options.map((option) => ({
        label: option,
        value: option
      }))}
    />
  );
```